# Can't get this simple sed command

Tags: linux, shell, sed, pipe

I'm having a problem with sed and i can't figure it out, and i'm also amateur.

The objective of my code is to keep monitoring a file(OutputFile.dat) until possible strings(NaN or STOP) are found and then kill the program running on the background. It worked when I'd tried only one string. However when I'd tried to implement more possible matches the code didn't work out.

```
    ../program inputfile &> OutputFile.dat &
    tail -f OutputFile.dat | sed -n '/NaN/q;/STOP/q'
    killall program
```

I've tried a lot of different things but i can't figure this out. Alternative suggestions to achieve the same thing are also welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `  egrep 'NaN|STOP'  ` will find the strings , not sure about second step, perhaps look for non-zero return code, then kill ???

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky due to buffering and race conditions. The current problems with your code are:

1. OutputFile.dat is created asynchronously in the background and may not be there when `tail` tries to look for it.

   You can fix this by opening the file synchronously
2. `program` may buffer output into larger chunks for efficiency reasons, because it doesn't think you care about timing.

   You can try to fix this by either asking `program` not to buffer, or by using `stdbuf` on GNU/Linux.
3. After `sed` recognizes a match, tail will need to detect and write another buffer-full of data before it realizes that, exits, and lets the script continue.

   You can work around this by structuring your script to wait for `sed` but not for `tail`.

Since you say your script works for one keyword, the showstopper for you is likely #3, if your second keyword appears towards the end or a pause in the output.

All together, this would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
( stdbuf -o 0 -e 0 ../program inputfile & ) &> OutputFile.dat
sed -n '/NaN/q;/STOP/q' <(tail -f OutputFile.dat)
killall program
```

Comment: that other guy, thank you for the answer, that actually solved the problem. However i think i might be having problems with the buffering. I'm working on linking a matlab code(optimization process) into a linux program, and i need to keep reading the outputs in order to check for possible errors. When i run your sugestion only on the prompt, it works, however, when i run several time through matlab, i get stuck on the terminal. When this happens, i check one of the output files, and the program has already finished. It seems that the sh can't finish. Do you have any idea why, or any solution ?

Comment: If you run this several times in parallel, all the instances will compete for the name "OutputFile.dat". Make sure each instance writes to a different filename.

Comment: I'm not running in parallel, to avoid this problem of writing the same file. I can't change the output of the program (the one that the program writes), therefore i can't run in parallel.